# OpenOffice Calc - Hyperlink dropdown list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

I have a problem with my hyperlink formula, it worked fine in Excel but when using it in ubuntu the hyperlink doesn't work it might be a syntax error

FORMULA :

```
=HYPERLINK("[base.xlsx]RECORRIDOS!"&$BASE.Q4,$BASE.Q4)
```

what is does is what it changes the hyperlink name depending on what you choose in the dropdown list in the cell beside it, and when clicking it it takes you to another sheet where the list is to the cell that you chose in the dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use [HYPERLINK](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#HYPERLINK) to go to another sheet named "RECORRIDOS" in Calc, to the cell address given in Q4.

```
=HYPERLINK("#RECORRIDOS."&Q4,"Go to "&Q4)
```

For Apache OpenOffice you may need to use `;` instead of `,` to separate arguments.

One difference between Excel and Calc is that Excel uses `!` where Calc uses `.` in addresses.

Comment: ok so for excel [ ] is for the file and ! is for the sheet. I'm guessing for OpenOffice # is for the sheet and what is . for? you don't have to add the file in to the hyperlink adress? I tried your formula but still says reference invalid

Comment: The question asked how to go to another cell in another sheet.  If you want to know more than this, edit the question and provide a specific example.  In particular, it does not tell what "BASE.Q4" is.  Also, please look at the HYPERLINK documentation mentioned in my answer.